java.nio.file.Files.exists() uses a lot of memory
I'm profiling my application and java.nio.file.Files is appearing as the top hotspot for memory usage (profiled with JProfile).

This doesn't make sense to me because the application is running a lot of XSLT transformations and storing the results in memory.  While it is showing up as a top-contender for memory usage, I wouldn't expect it to be surpassed by a java.nio.file.Files.exists() call.
This is the code in question that's causing the memory hotspot:
public static FileStatus getFileStatus(Path path) {
  try {
    var exists = Files.exists(path);
    var isDirectory = exists && Files.isDirectory(path);
    var lastModified = exists ? Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis() : 0;
    var size = exists ? Files.size(path) : 0;

    return new FileStatus(exists, isDirectory, lastModified, size);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}

Why is Files.exists() taking up so much memory, and is there a way fix the memory usage?  This is running on AdoptOpenJDK 11 and running on Windows 10.

1675 allocations doesn't sound like a lot, does that roughly correspond to the number of files you expect to be checked? Also be careful that sometimes memory instrumentation can influence the optimizations and the hotspots you see are simply the ones that are mostly optimized away (due to escape analysis and similar tools) when running without instrumentation. Sometimes less powerful methods like memory snapshots can provide a less granular, but more useful picture.

I couldn't explain why one call to Files.exists has high memory impact - but it is a file system access so do expect it to behave as would accessing a file every time.
However, all those calls you use make use of Files.readAttributes internally, so you can reduce 3x filesystem accesses (and allocations for same) by changing getFileStatus to make one readAttributes call:
public static FileStatus getFileStatus(Path path) {
    try {
        BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        
        return new FileStatus(true, 
                              attrs.isDirectory(), 
                              attrs.lastModifiedTime().toMillis(), 
                              attrs.isDirectory() ? 0L : attrs.size());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Does not exist:
        return new FileStatus(false, false, 0L, 0L);
    }
}

Note: On Windows (and WSL), Files.size on a directory can return non-zero. This is not the size of the contents. If you want to keep that behaviour, use attrs.size() as the last parameter to new FileStatus()

I'm marking this answer as correct since it did fix the original issue.  However, now the hotspot is appearing in a Files.newInputStream(path) call.  It's behaving as if there's some sort of caching mechanism running in the background for these filesystem paths.  e.g. it was allocating a bunch of memory for the Files.exists call which made the Files.newInputStream() call reuse the same memory that was allocated for the Files.exists call.  However, now that the Files.exists call isn't being called anymore, now it's allocating the memory for the FIles.newInputStream() call.
